# how to create <input type="text"/> tag that should be allowed data in multiple lines. dont say to use textarea tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to create `<input type="text"/>` tag that should be allowed data in multiple lines. dont say to use textarea tag. i know that but I want only with `<input>` tag because `<input>` tag has value attribute. so when i get value from xml file, I should be get dynamically using jquery syntax..

Comment: You can't.  If you want multiple lines, use a textarea.

Comment: Why are you not using "textarea tag" ??

Comment: Does XML have anything to do with your question at all?

Answer (score 8):

Use a `<textarea>` tag, or forget about multiple lines. There, I said it.

You do realize you can use `$('textarea').val()` to grab the value, right? You were probably thinking about `$('input').attr('value')`, which isn't exactly the best way to grab an input value. As a matter of fact, you should be using `.val()` for *both* inputs and textareas.